# How to check validation on the Div Element using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I am trying to add validation on below field i am getting error message but its still letting me to save the field ,I am not sure where i am wrong please help..

So far tried code...

validate.html

```
<form name="createProcessFormName"
    name="form" role="form" class="form-horizontal"
    kendo-validator="validator" k-validate-on-blur="false"
    k-options="myValidatorOptions" ng-submit="validate($event) && createProcessFormName.$invalid">

    <div class="col-md-7">

        <div multiselect-dropdown-tree ng-model="nonPersistentProcess.geoLocations" ng-class="{'disabled': disableGeoLocations}" disable-children="true" options="treeviewOptions"></div>
            <p class="status" ng-show="geoLocationRequired">*GeoLocation is required field*</p>
        </div>

        <button require-control-point="PROCESS_ADD"
            ng-hide="editMode" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button"
            ng-click="validate($event)">Save</button>
```

validate.js

```
$scope.validate = function ($event) {
    if(!$scope.nonPersistentProcess.geoLocations.length || $scope.nonPersistentProcess.epcfKey || $scope.nonPersistentProcess.legalEnty || $scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey){
        if($scope.createProcessFormName.$invalid){
            $scope.geoLocationRequired = true;
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the if condition to:

```
if(!$scope.nonPersistentProcess.geoLocations.length || !$scope.nonPersistentProcess.epcfKey || !$scope.nonPersistentProcess.legalEnty || !$scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey)
```